# MySql Query result only first column

Tags: mysql

My query that i use is

```
SELECT item1, item2, item3, item4 FROM table  WHERE id ='99'
```

should result **1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8**, but i got only **1** , can i get them all in 1 column like **Items** ?

```
+-------+--------+----------+---------+---------+
| id    | item1  |   item2  |  item3  |  item4  |   
+-------+--------+----------+---------+---------+
|  99   |    1   |     2    |    3    |    4    | 
|  99   |    5   |     6    |    7    |    8    | 
|  92   |    1   |     2    |    3    |    4    | 
|  92   |    1   |     2    |    3    |    4    | 
+-------+--------+----------+---------+---------+
```

Function

```
function getInv($id)
    {
        global $database;
        $stmt = $dbh->user("SELECT CONCAT(item1,', ',item2,', ',item3,', ',item4) Items
        FROM table  WHERE id= ? ORDER BY Items");
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
        
        if($result)
        return convert_number($result[0]);
        else {
        return '---';
    }
```

View Page

```
<?php print getInv($user['id']); ?>
```

Comment: Your problem is confusing. Are you saying that your query only give 1 column? According to the table it should give one line (1,2,3,4).

Comment: if i use CONCAT, is taking first column too, can be a problem from php ?

Comment: Please clarify with including actual desired results and explain how your query is expected to give those desired results.

Comment: @Stu updated my quetion

Comment: You are showing two different queries. The first query will return two rows with 4 columns each. If not, either your table structure or your query is not what you are showing here. The second query (in the php statement) will (given you are also querying for id 99) two rows, with one column each, `"1,2,3,4"` and `"5,6,7,8"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To produce your expected result you could use:

```
select group_concat(CONCAT_WS(' ',item1, item2, item3, item4) SEPARATOR ' ')  as my_column
FROM my_table  WHERE id =99
group by id;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> my_column
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cc3a602dac578e698c5d35c8b26ad6aa)

Answer (score 1):

You could use GROUP_CONCAT and CONCAT to get theresult, but it would be better to have some kind of order for the line, so that the result is more deterministc

> ```
> CREATE TABLE item (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `item1` INTEGER,
>   `item2` INTEGER,
>   `item3` INTEGER,
>   `item4` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO item
>   (`id`, `item1`, `item2`, `item3`, `item4`)
> VALUES
>   ('99', '1', '2', '3', '4'),
>   ('99', '5', '6', '7', '8'),
>   ('92', '1', '2', '3', '4'),
>   ('92', '1', '2', '3', '4');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`item1`, ',', `item2`,',',  `item3`,',' , `item4` ) ) AS intes FROM item WHERE `id` = 99
> ```
>
> ```
> | intes           |
> | :-------------- |
> | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9ae1078f4725fcef6f545be1ca9968ed)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
select group_concat(item1+",",",",item2,",",item3,",",item4) as result from my_table where (id="99") order by id
```

> ```
> |result          |
> |1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 |
> ```